# How to create a Render Background with cartoon bean sunlight for composite

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I want the cartoon sunlight in the background for a composite like this: [image]

Please don't forget to demonstrate pictures, gifs, or upload blends files. to make it easy to understand.

Comment: ...and you did try what...? ever checked out sun beams?

Comment: i recommend not writing that "Please don't forget to demonstrate pictures, gifs, or upload blends files. to make it easy to understand." because i think this is pretty outrageous ...and this might be the reason why you get seldom answers to your questions

Comment: Hello, is it for a still picture or for animation?

Comment: For a pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stretch a *Noise Texture* on the surface of a cone or cylinder. For the white background you can mix your noise with a white color, with a gradient on Y as factor:

[image]

Result in camera view:

[image]